# Should I use JQuery to add some value to a Hidden Text Box?

Tags: jquery

I am stuck over a question in which I got to make a Hidden Text box to store a value.
But I have seen that JQuery is capable to add some value to a Hidden Text box.
I am not sure which is the best way to hide the value which will be stored to the Database.
Please look at the codes below:

Traditional way:

```
<input type="hidden" id="data[Test][quote]" value="hello" />
```

Using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#data\\[Test\\]\\[quote\\]").val("hello"); 
});       
<input type="hidden" id="data[Test][quote]" />
```

Please advise.

Comment: Basic question should be, why do you care to set value using javascript when you can do it the traditional way. You would only need to do that, in case you want to set value runtime, based on some events on page.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to set it with JavaScript? What "value" are you looking to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unless the parameter has to change on-the-fly, don't use jQuery to do something already possible with plain old HTML.
2. That is not a hidden *text box*; it's just a tag to include some input data without rendering any form control on the browser.

Answer (score 3):

If you can do it without JavaScript / jQuery, do it without.

Comment: Good simple answer. You have my +1 atleast. but people like complex solution even to simple problems.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, you can even use raw javascript for that at least:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var el = document.getElementById("data\\[Test\\]\\[quote\\]");
  el.value = 'Hello';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you don't need to use a hidden field, use jQuery`s`.data()` method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.data(document.body, 'data', 'hello');
    alert($.data(document.body, 'data'));
});
```